# Azure spatial anchors child object in Unity

Tags: ios, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I did a simple experiment after successfully completing the cross platform quick start Microsoft tutorials for HoloLens and iOS. I simply added a child capsule to the default cube demo object. When I created an anchor in the HoloLens app, the capsule was visible floating above the cube during anchor creation and when being recalled. However when I tried to view the anchor in iOS, only the cube was seen (capsule child object was not visible). If I created the anchor in the iOS app, only the cube was visible during creation and when being recalled. However, when the anchor that was created in the iOS app was located by the HoloLens app, the capsule child object WAS visible. So, clearly the iOS app was storing the child object with the anchor it created, it just doesn’t display the object. Any idea why? How would one go about placing a game object interactively and then making that object a spatial anchor itself? That would probably get around the lack of displaying the child object in the iOS app, as the demo cube object was seen in both the HoloLens and iOS apps.

Comment: No one will have an idea why things are not working, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to provide some code/background to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Gary, Azure Spatial Anchors is only sharing the world position between the clients not the holograms. In you case the cube is in the correct position and because you added the asset cube in HoloLens you see it in HoloLens. If you want another Hologram in iOS you will need to create the asset in iOS and have it in the scene.

If you want to have the same holograms across clients you need to do the work in all the clients and attach the world pose that you will receive from Azure Spatial Anchors Service.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Yes, I was suffering from a misconception! I watched a YouTube video last night that Rene Schulte and Paris Morgan gave at Microsoft Develop that really helped drive that home. They presented a demo app and posted source code that should help, except it is written in JavaScript. Please let me know if a wayfinding tutorial for Unity gets posted using different objects with properties stored in a Cosmos DB. I am much better at learning through mimicry than trying to translate across languages... Thank you so much!